# React JS and Node API call optimization for better performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Hola fellow developers!

I have a quick question about best practices for optimizing code on the back end and front end for better performance and faster loading times.

Here is a function example that I've written, which grabs a few users from MongoDB and sends them to my React App to be displayed. That's what I've done on the back-end:

```js
router.get("/get-followers/new/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User not found...");
        let following = [...user.following];
        let users = await User.find({ 'name': { $in: following } }).select('name profilePic photos');
        res.send(users);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        next();
    }
});
```

And here is the following function on the front-end that sorts the users and updates the state:

```js
 const getUsers = async (end) => {
        try {
            if (context.curUser._id) {
                const { data } = await http.get(`${config.apiEndpoint}/followers/get-followers/new/${context.curUser._id}`);
                data.map(user => {
                    user.photos.reverse();
                });
                const newPhotos = [];
                data.map(user => {
                    user.photos.map(photo => {
                        let curPhoto = {
                            profilePic: user.profilePic.data,
                            user: { name: user.name, _id: user._id },
                            photo: {
                                data: photo.data, contentType: photo.contentType,
                                likes: photo.likes, date: photo.date,
                                comments: photo.comments, _id: photo._id
                            }
                        };
                        newPhotos.push(curPhoto);
                    })
                });
                newPhotos.sort((a, b) => a.photo.date < b.photo.date);
                if (slice > newPhotos.length) { setShowLoad(false) };
                const slicedPhotos = newPhotos.slice(0, end);
                setUsers(slicedPhotos);
            }
            else { return }
        } catch (ex) {
            console.error('Something went wrong while getting feed.');
        }
    };
```

Although the code works brilliantly, it takes about 3 seconds for everything to be displayed on the page and I was just wondering if I'm making any mistakes on the Front-end or the Back-end. And is there any way that I could improve the code and in general write faster loading code?

Comment: first question, did you put an index on `name`? I would suggest to go with a mongodb aggregation pipeline instead of making 2 requests to the database.

Comment: I didn't ... and I also have no clue how the aggregation pipeline works. I guess there is a great reason for why my API calls take so long ...

Comment: execute this code once `User.createIndex({ name: 1 })` it should create an index on name. The problem is that you do a whole collection scan on `name` witch is pretty slow special with `$in`